# Best way to access variables unique to derived class through container of baseclass

Tags: c++

So I have a vector of pointers to baseclass, which is used to hold all instances of derived classes.

Base class:

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

Class Base
{
  public:

    virtual void DoSomething();

};

#endif
```

A derived class:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "base.h"

Class Derived : public Base
{
  public:

    void DoSomething();

    float y;

};

#endif
```

With these things being stored inside:

```
std::vector<Base*> theVec;
```

The question being, what is the best way to access the float variable "y" that exists only in Derived?

I could have a virtual function in Base that is specified in Derived to return a variable, where access looks like:

```
theVec[0]->GetVar("y");
```

but when Derived is likely to have multiple variables of different types that are not in base this seems like it will end up being quite messy. Are there any ways to make access to a unique variable in Derived more generic?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I would say the design of such classes is bad to begin with, if it requires you to do things like that.

Comment: What's wrong with `dynamic_case<Derived *>(theVec[0])->y` ?

Comment: I should perhaps have included more information, theVec is likely to be holding multiple different types of derived classes, all of which may well have variables that are unique to themselves, and accessing them directly would make life easier.

If there is no good solution to this particular problem however, i'll likely rethink the implementation as suggested. I was just hoping I had missed something basic

Comment: @Ernest: you're dereferencing a null pointer if `dynamic_cast` fails.

Comment: @Gra42: rather than accessing the variables of the different objects, can't you give `Base` a virtual method and put the work that uses those various member variables into the respective classes? That's by far the best solution for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elegant solution to this problem. If you have it, your design is probably flawed, and you should rethink it. Having special cases for sub-classes defeats the purpose of polymorphism (although I admit that sometimes it is the only solution).

Comment: Often the overhead and complexity of abstracting a full polymorphic solution to a problem is just not worth it if the a simple dynamic_cast can be used. That is, if the *proper* OOP solution would require hundreds of lines of code and the dynamic_cast would require only a handful, it may make sense to use dynamic_cast.

Comment: @edA: I agree with all but the first word - in my experience, such cases are rare.

Comment: I mean "span of career" *often*; maybe I'm just old. I agree that within a given project it should be used sparingly.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with `dynamic_cast`, but it should be used cautiously.

Answer (score 4):

You use `dynamic_cast`.

```
if (Derived* ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(theVec[0])) {
    // do something here
}
```